# When `lang = "jp"` is given to an attribute, the ellipsis is vertically centered

Tags: html, localization, internationalization, lang

when lang = "jp" is given to an attribute, the ellipsis is vertically centered like this
[image]

But i want to like this
[image]

I want to keep the font family and lang but only the ellipsis down

Comment: But so, you do not want `lang=jp`. Glyphs on fonts depend on language (and if you check, also the letters are rendered slightly different then in standard Latin script) (and please do no mix-up typesetting, but if you know well typesetting).

Comment: So, it is impossible, but if you should use a font which use low ellipsis for JP language (or you tell the font to use latin script for the ellipsis, but this is nearly equivalent to change language, which you do not want).